# executing NSTask in the background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shell, nstask

I'm executing a shell script using NSTask but the problem is that the shell script is one of those scripts that keeps running until you press control+c. It starts up fine but then my mac application just waits for it to end. How can I make it so that it detaches the task from the mac application and goes and runs it in a background.

Comment: Can you place your code?

Comment: I'm using the STPrivilegedTask library found at http://www.sveinbjorn.org/STPrivilegedTask

Comment: this don't use NSTask ... use http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `waitUntilExit` or otherwise run the task synchronously.   If the task has lots of output, make sure you read and process the data or else an i/o buffer will fill and it'll block.

In general, you shouldn't be using NSTask for a daemon like operation anyway.   You should be using launchd.

Comment: do you have an example of using launchd in cocoa? My main requirement is to run the shell script under admin privilege.

Comment: And for a useful interface to launchd configuration.. http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19879/lingon